# Uneven Load Distribution in Kubernetes Pods with Multithreaded Execution using fork join pool

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, kubernetes, java-8, forkjoinpool

I have a Spring Boot application where I had a CPU-intensive function performing 43 non-dependent function calls sequentially, resulting in significant execution time. To optimize performance, I parallelized these function calls using a ForkJoinPool. However, in a Kubernetes environment, enabling this multithreaded flow causes approximately 90-95% of requests to be directed to a single pod, leading to uneven load distribution among pods and service failure.

Here's how I implemented the multithreaded execution:

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(2);
CompletableFuture<?> var1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> f(parameters1), forkJoinPool);
CompletableFuture<?> var2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> f(parameters2), forkJoinPool);
// Repeat for var3 to var43...

CompletableFuture<Void> allOfFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(var1, var2, var3, ..., var43);

try {
    allOfFutures.get(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    // Handle exception
}
```

Despite parallelizing the function calls, the load distribution among pods remains uneven, with a single pod handling the majority of requests despite load balancer policy set as round robin. I'm seeking insight into why this might be happening in a Kubernetes environment.

Any suggestion or solution is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to parallelize. Are you trying to execute the var1,2,3 in a different pods? Or do the var1,2,3 send some network requests that you expect to be routed to a different pods?

Comment: I am trying to execute function f() in parallel for all 43 different parameters which are not dependent on each other. This function f() is purely computing some data and not making any external network or database calls. This entire process is happening in a single pod

Comment: so how is loadbalancer related here if there are no network requests?

Comment: load balancer is distributing the load when request is sent to the server. There are no external network calls.

Comment: so, is your problem that 90% of the requests are routed to the pod that is busy to run the functions var1/2/3. Or your problem that the load balancer is not balancing the execution of var1/2/3 on different pods?